Error: Native module not found, js engine: hermes
const socket = new SockJS(URL);


packaget.json:
"sockjs-client": "^1.6.1",


I have a piece of code for initializing a STOMP client to handle WebSocket connections in my React Native project. The code works perfectly in Android, but I encounter an issue on iOS. When running the code on iOS with Hermes enabled, I receive the following error:
Error: Native module not found, js engine: hermes

The error specifically appears when the following line is included:
const socket = new SockJS(URL);

If I comment out or remove this line, the error goes away, but the WebSocket connection does not establish either, which breaks the functionality.
Important Note: The code works well on Android, and this issue only arises on iOS.
Could you help me resolve this issue?
